# IE8 z-index mess persistent with bigger z-index on parent

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, z-index

I have a z-index (well, I think) issue on this website : http://dev.golfuse-ag.com/

I had to use a 100% width+height div to create an extra background. Now, in IE8, I get this z-index interpretation issue even if I had a greater number for parents elements.

The DIVs in questions are #bckg, #wrapper and #mid

Tried a bunch of crazy things and... nothing close to OK.

If anyone can give me a hand with this one, you are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ie will not let you have parents with lower z-index than child.

You can try z-index: -1 on your parent if you want, but i'm not sure it will work. IE does not interpret z-index like you want :S You'll probably need to put your background on another element, out of this element.